# Clustering extracted text from images?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have an image from which I have 'extracted' text from - basically put bounding boxes around the letters.
In a similar fashion shown below, [image]  except the difference is that instead of the coins, there are letters. I am required to cluster the said bounding boxes according to the 'row' they are in - so for instance I would have to cluster the top row of coins or 'letters' (in my case). I can't seem to figure out an efficient way to do this?

One very crude approach I have is that I count the number of bounding boxes in each line and cluster them accordingly, but this is not efficient at all.

Comment: If you're using OpenCV to find the bounding boxes you can sort the contours with  [imutils.contours.sort_contours()](https://github.com/jrosebr1/imutils/blob/master/imutils/contours.py#L7) with the `left-to-right` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the distance from one letter to its neighbour is different to the one below it, you can use K - Means clustering. Alternatively, you can use DBSCAN with a suitable epsilon.

Considering the given example you should evaluate whether clustering is really necessary. As you mentioned: Assuming you have information about each 'row' (e.g. difference in height from the last known row), you can check if a bounding box contains the same x/y coordinate (depending if you are in rows/cols or cols/rows format).
Implementing this efficiently is probably faster than any clustering you will be doing.

Comment: ```> Find average size of all bounding boxes in the image, decide tolerance of rows based on this number.
 > Find the center coordinate of each of the bounding boxes 
 > Compare the center coordinate of each bounding box to the next one.
 > If the centers are within tolerance then club them together ``` Do you think this approach might work?

Comment: As long as the max deviation in your bounding box from your calculated average is still smaller than the distance to the next row - yes. Sounds like a good approach, that's what i had in mind. Best of luck!